# how can i delete an element in numpy array and use a for loop in python and its index

Tags: python, numpy, loops

This is what I made and it doesn't work, I made a for loop and I use it to get the index and use it in another thing why doesn't it work or can I found another method to delete the element and use the index of it.

Here is [some of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7KAJ.png)

```
X1_train, X1_test, y1_train, y1_test = train_test_split(EclipseFeautres, EclipseClass, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
E_critical_class=y1_train.copy()
E_critical_class = E_critical_class[E_critical_class != 1]
for x in range(len(E_critical_class)):
if(E_critical_class[x]==1):
    E=np.delete(E_critical_class,x)
```

Comment: the website didn't let me to write the code

Comment: @TeneshVignesan ok thank u very much

Comment: The `delete` result is assigned to `E`, but that variable isn't used anywhere.  So changes that you make in one loop are just thrown away.  In general though it is a bad idea to delete items one by one in a loop, even when working with lists.  The array/list size changes with deletes.  It would be better to collect  a list of delete locations, and call `np.delete` just once with that list.

Comment: @hpaulj i get what u said but i'm asking this question because I need the same index to delete another elements in another numpy array and I use E list to print it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is something like filtering of an array.
You want to drop all elements *== 1*.

Assume that the source array (*arr*) contains:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0, 3, 7, 1])
```

so it contains 3 elements *== 1* (to be dropped).

A much simpler way to do it is to use *boolean indexing* and save the
result back to the original variable:

```
arr = arr[arr != 1]
```

The result is:

```
array([0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 3, 7])
```

as you wish - with all *one*s dropped.

Answer (score 0):

```
#dizi icinde olan ve kendini tekrarlayan sayiyi delete etme!!!!!!
#to delete the repeated element in the numpy array
import numpy as np
a = np.array([10, 0, 0, 20, 0, 30, 40, 50, 0, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100,0])
print("Original array:")
print(a)
index=np.zeros(0)
print("index=",index)
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]==0:
        index=np.append(index, i)
print("index=",index)
new_a=np.delete(a,index)
print("new_a=",new_a)
```